# OpenID Connect and OAuth2 for user management using .NET Core

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect

Where can I get sample project for user management implemented with OAuth2 and OpenID Connect?

I have searched everywhere and all I get is just plain theory. I need a reference to understand this concept. So someone kindly guide me.

Comment: AspnetZero did that in their 11.3.0 (latest today) version

Comment: See here: https://andrewlock.net/an-introduction-to-openid-connect-in-asp-net-core/ - or here: https://damienbod.com/2019/11/01/user-claims-in-asp-net-core-using-openid-connect-authentication/ or here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2 - or a gazillion other sites found by simple searching ....

Comment: @marc_s These links only have OIDC. There is no OAuth2 implemented in it.

Answer (score 0):

As long you just need implemented samples to understand the concept...

The different concepts are the different flows.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4

The newer version requires a license for usage.

Unfortunatly the two devs said in almost every talk I watched that "using their library does not prevent one from reading the specs".

Feel free to ask questions in the comments. I am definitely not a pro but may I can help out.